# How to filter all files of type containing a pattern

Tags: grep, find

I want to locate all the `.gradle` files containing some text in my project.  Right now I am in `\Git\ProjectRoot`.  I run

`find . -type f -name \*.gradle`

I want to search the contents of all the files in the list for the pattern `grep -i hibernate`.  I want the result to be a list of all these files by name.

Comment: You want to search for *pattern* `grep -i hibernate`, or search case-insensitively for pattern `hibernate`? Regardless, if your `grep` supports `--include` globs you should be able to avoid `find` altogether e.g. `grep -iRl 'hibernate' --include='*.gradle' .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another clause to your `find` statement:

```
find . -type f -name \*.gradle -exec grep -il hibernate {} +
```

This will give a bunch of .gradle files to grep to work on and grep will then list the names (if any) of those that had the hibernate string in them in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: I get why you added `-exec`.  Can you elaborate on the purpose of the last two tokens `{} +`?  I don't understand what this does.

Comment: The `{} +` are a way to add multiple filenames to the `grep`'s arguments list. OTW, with the standard predicate `{} \;` we are suboptimally utilizing both `find` and `grep` by invoking `grep` once per file. When `grep` has that facility of handling multiple files at one go, then why not use them is the mantra here.